# Does it make sense to have diverging Kalman gain and covariance when system accuracy worsens over time?

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, bayesian-estimation, unscented-kalman-filter

I've developed an UKF for a system, whose dynamics change slowly over time. The state & measurement equations are quadratic and linear equations fitted to experimental data in the following form:
$$ \begin{aligned}
    x &= p_1m^2 + p_2m + p_3 \\
    y &= q_1x + q2
\end{aligned} \tag 1$$

I then converted my state equation into an iterative form:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x_{k+1}&= p_1(m_k + \Delta m)^2 + p_2(m_k + \Delta m) + p3 \\
&= (p_1m_{k}^2 + p_2m_k + p_3) + (p_1 \Delta m^2 + 2p_2m_k \Delta m + p_2 \Delta m) \\
  &= x_k + f(m_k, \Delta m)
\end{aligned}\end{equation} \tag 2$$

where $\Delta m = m_{k+1} - m_k$

After implementing an UKF on this system, I noticed that my state covariance & Kalman gain increases over time, instead of converging, possibly because the model accuracy worsens over time as the system ages. The innovation, state covariance (P) & Kalman gain are plotted as follows. Note that x axis is not time but a variable related to the age of the system, and it starts from 1 (right side) and goes towards 0 as time progresses.
[image: Innovation, state covariance (P) & Kalman gain]

I don't have data points beyond the ones I currently have, so can't tell if it will eventually converge, but that doesn't matter anyway because I'm only interested in the current window of time tested.

I was wondering if there are anything I sohuld be concerned about this, since converging covariance & gain are usually suggested? Should I still aim to get them to converge somehow?

Comment: can you relate the accuracy / noise variance over time to the gain over time, maybe in a plot?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question.  Certainly, even with a plain old Kalman, if you start with a small-enough state covariance and a large-enough process noise then you'll see the state covariance increase over time.

Comment: It would help if you would _edit your question_ with more information.  It would _really_ help if you could give us a small "toy" model that represents your system, or if it's small enough and you can share, just give us your system description and your filter's math.

Comment: @TimWescott Sorry for the delay, but I've updated the description w/ both the models & the plots. Hope it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Your (1) isn't a state-space equation, your (2) isn't consistent with (1), and your covariance matrix and Kalman gain don't increase -- they decrease, as you'd like to happen.  You either need to edit this question **heavily** to tell us what the **actual system is that you're trying to model** so we can help you model it correctly, or you need to abandon this question for the moment and start a new one.  Note that your system model needs to be dynamic: $d\mathbf x / dt = f(\mathbf x, u)$, $\mathbf y = g(x)$.  If it's not a dynamic system, there's not much sense in a Kalman filter.

Comment: @TimWescott For the equations, why do you say (1) & (2) are not consistent? For the plots, I should have mentioned that the x-axis is not time but another variable that starts from 1, so the plots actually move from right to left if that makes sense.

Comment: The **last** line of (2) would make sense if the first line of (1) were $\frac d {dt} x = p_1m^2 + p_2m + p_3$.  However, the **first** line of (2) appears as if you're trying to make a difference equation where $m$ is a state variable, yet $m$ does not appear on the left side of any equation.  **It doesn't make sense** unless $x$ is a vector that includes $m$ -- which you have not stipulated.

Comment: "I should have mentioned that..." please fix that by _editing your question_ with that information.  Or better yet, since there's not a lot of Kalman experts on this group to start with, _present the data in a canonical form_.  Note that StackExchange is kinda weird as forums go: it wants questions with complete bodies and no information really needed in the comments, sufficient to drive an answer.